# Find strings in a C++ file with regex

Tags: c++, regex

I have a large project with many CPP files containing hardcoded english strings. The idea is now to enable translations, so I want to replace in each CPP file with a function call that will return the strings depending on the language.

The idea is to write another program that would detect the strings within the CPP code and replace them with a function that returns a const string based on some unique index that will be built automatically.

For example: `std::cout << "Hello";` to `std::cout << s(1);` or `MessageBox(0,L"You are wrong!",L"Error",MB_OK);` to `MessageBox(0,s(2),s(3),MB_OK)`;

The app then will create a new CPP file with those changes and build an index with the original english strings that would now be able to be translated.

The question is, what would be a good way to use regex to detect strings?

I 've thought of `/(?:")(?=(?:[^"]|"[^]*")*$)/g` (as I found online, I 'm not experienced with regex). Ideally it would catch `L""` (since most of the strings are unicode), raw stuff like LR"(xxx)" (altough those are a few).

Of course, I plan to have my app present me a list which I can review the proposed changes so to not accidentally fail, but I 'd wish the manual intervention would be minimal.

Perhaps later I can build a VS extension for that.

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that's why I want to have my app present me the proposed changes. I don't care if there are errors, I will fix them manually. The idea is to do some 90% of the work based in common strings I have in the CPPs which I hope there 's a way to detect, not for weird exceptions that may be there.

Comment: This is actually very hard. Strings can be broken up into multiple line, there can be multiple adjacent strings which will need concatenation (with possible comments between the strings), there can be raw string literals which needs special handling, not to mention all possible escapes and Unicode characters. And of course handling wide- and narrow-character strings in a nice way. Oh, and macros that expands to strings.

Comment: You definetly need to consider comments and escape sequences. Furthermore I'm not sure how you'd want preprocessor (e.g. `#define STRINGIFY(x) #x`) and string literal concatenation to be handled...

Comment: Btw: There could be a chance that a Qt related tool exists that you could adjust for your purposes. After all Qt does have translation functionality via [`tr`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#tr) and it's a widely used lib.

Comment: Using a regex is the wrong way to go about this. Producing multiple executable binaries is the wrong way to go about this. Your program needs to employ an i18n library. Possible duplicate [Resources for i18n in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195497/resources-for-i18n-in-c)

Comment: I would not produce multiple executables.

Comment: i18n libraires tend to use `xxx("English string", extra_arg)` as format (with different `xxx`/`extra_arg` depending of lib and plural support(`tr`, `gettext`)).